# Can't edit input in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I'm having an issue with editing a value in my React app. I'm aware of how controlled components work, and my problem isn't related to that.

I can paste text into it and see state for the input change, but when I try to change it myself nothing happens. The input resides inside of a TableHeader component.

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

class TableHeader extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        columnFilterText : "",
        filterBoxOpen : false
    }
    this.toggleSortBox = this.toggleSortBox.bind(this);
    this.handleColumnInputChange = this.handleColumnInputChange.bind(this);
}

toggleSortBox(event, value) {
    if(event.target === event.currentTarget) {
        this.setState({
            filterBoxOpen: !this.state.filterBoxOpen
        });
    }
}

handleColumnInputChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({
        columnFilterText: event.target.value
    })
}

render() {
    let tableHeaderClasses = classNames({
     "sortable" : true,
     "filter-box-open" : this.state.filterBoxOpen
    });
    let sortOptionClasses = classNames({
     "sort-option" : true

    });
    return (
        <th className={tableHeaderClasses} onClick={this.toggleSortBox}>
            <div className="sort-box">
                <div className="sort-option-container">
                    <div  className={sortOptionClasses}>Sort - ascending</div>
                </div>
                <div className="sort-option-container">
                    <div className={sortOptionClasses}>Sort - descending</div>
                </div>
                <hr className="divider" />
                <input onChange={this.handleColumnInputChange} type="text" value={this.state.columnFilterText} />
                <div className="row">
                    <button className="six columns">Apply</button>
                    <button className="six columns">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {this.props.label}
        </th>
    );
}
}

export default TableHeader;
```

I've checked if it's a css issue, by disabling styles, but the input field is still disabled, so no luck there. Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce your issue locally, all your code seems correct. Can you post a codepen perhaps where the issue is occurring?

Comment: I am able to change by both typing and copying the value of input element. It seems that it's working but maybe you may have problem in the page where this component is used.

Comment: remove `console.log(event)` inside `handleColumnInputChange` method.

Comment: @MayankShukla Might be the issue, at least it was the cause for the infinite loop I observed (due to stack snippets hijacking the console)

Comment: i had this problem before, don't remember exactly how i solved it, but the easiest solution is to replace `value` attribute with `defaultValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The reason for this was that I had a keyDown event on the parent component for keyboard navigation, with `event.preventDefault();` which of course affected the child component.

Thanks to everyone for contributing and for trying to help!